# Boost library finds targets but does not compile

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I installed boost on debian linux.

Now I tried to run the test "hello world" example.

First I go into the folder

```
/tools/build/v2/example/hello
```

there are some files:

```
hello.cpp jamroot.jam
```

then I type into the console:

```
/tools/build/v2/bin/b2 toolset=gcc
```

**I get the message:**

> ...found 8 targets...

Thats all. No error but also no compile message and no output file: "hello".

The same with `./bjam toolset=gcc install:`

**I get the message:**

> ...found 613 targets...
>
> ...updating 7 targets...

but no compilation or other message.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b2 or b2 toolset=gcc is not enough.

I have to type in b2 **release** in order to compile.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/bbv2/tutorial.html